# How to handle buffer error while validating user input

Tags: c, validation, scanf, user-input

I need to read in user input as an integer to pass it to my other function. If I use my validation (code below), it crashes after 4 bad inputs. I'm not completely sure if this is even a buffer error or not. But I also didn't find a proper way to validate my input and handle the errors. I didn't use `scanf(%d)` on purpose because I wanted to dodge the warning CLion is giving me when using it. I hope someone here can explain to me why my code is crashing after 4 bad inputs and how to fix it, or show me an alternative way.

```
char *userInput = malloc(100);
long amountOfPlayers;
//Todo: More Validation needed, bufferoverflow
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput) / sizeof(*userInput); i++) {
    char *end;
    printf("Please enter the amount of players: ");
    scanf("%s", userInput);
    amountOfPlayers = strtol(userInput, &end, 10);
    if (end == userInput) {
        printf("wasn't a number\n");
    }
    else if (end[0] != '\0') {
        printf("trailing characters after number %ld: %s\n", amountOfPlayers, end);
    }
    else
        return init_playerList(amountOfPlayers);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(userInput)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: Why are you using the size of `userInput` as the limit of the loop, anyway?

Comment: Man you solved the problem, i wanted to answer that the for loop isnt doing a lot of work here and i guess it can be changed out for a simple while(true), for fun i did it and now its working. Can you maybe explain me the mistake i did there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInput` is a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof(userInput)` returns the size of a pointer, typically 4 bytes. `sizeof(*userInput)` is `sizeof(char)`, which is `1`. So `sizeof(userInput) / sizeof(*userInput)` is 4, which means your `for` loop only executes 4 times. See [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

There's no need for a `for` loop, just use `while (true)`. You're not doing anything that iterates over the elements of `userInput`, it's just the buffer.

There's also no reason to allocate it with `malloc()`, you can simply declare:

```
char userInput[100];
```

You have a memory leak because you never `free(userInput)` before returning from the function. But if you declare it as an array this is not necessary.

TO prevent buffer overflow you should use:

```
scanf("%100s", userInput);
```

Comment: doesnt a pointer equals a one dimensional array ?
char *a = malloc(100) same as char a[100] ?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in many contexts, but pointers never become arrays.

Comment: thanks a lot barmar, ill take a look on your link, finally i can go to bed

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(userInput) / sizeof(*userInput)` won't return the number of elements, because `userInput` is a pointer, not an array. This only works for pure arrays. In case of pointer is always return the same value: size of a pointer divided by the size of the object.

```
int size = 100;
char *userInput = malloc(size);
if(userInput == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ....
}
```

would be correct.